# Any way to separate final Answer and Solution?

Tags: exam, exercises, exsheets, exercisebank

I am using `exam` package to typeset few problems along with its solutions.

```
\question Evaluate $\int \frac{x^{4}}{x^{2}+1} d x$
\begin{solution}
Solution: $\int \frac{\mathrm{x}^{4}}{\mathrm{x}^{2}+1} \mathrm{~d} \mathrm{x}=\int \frac{\mathrm{x}^{4}-1+1}{\mathrm{x}^{2}+1} \mathrm{~d} \mathrm{x}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
    &=\int \frac{x^{4}-1}{x^{2}+1}+\frac{1}{x^{2}+1} d x \\
    &=\int\left(x^{2}-1\right) d x+\int \frac{1}{x^{2}+1} d x \\
    &=\frac{x^{3}}{3}-x+\tan ^{-1} x+C
\end{aligned}
$$
\end{solution}
```

I want to separate "final answer" from the "solution".

So that I can give a handout containing:

1. just questions & final answers.
   [image]
2. Or sometimes just the questions (without answers or solutions).
3. Or sometimes questions and solutions.

I am hoping for something like this:

```
\question question
\answer answer %or even \begin{answer} \end{answer} <-- for final answer
\begin{solution}
  solution
\end{solution}
```

Now, I should be able to print just final answers using `\printanswers` (or some command like that) and printing of solutions controlled by `\printsolutions`.

I don't have any preference for `exam`package, I am using it because it has `\printanswers` and nice solution environment. I am open to use any other package.

**EDIT:** Adding some custom code to any latex packages/classes is also okay. I just need this thing to work. It would be ideal if there is a facility to deferred print the options.

Comment: Take a look at the `xsim` package

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda: I am a latex newbie, I have gone through the documentation. I found it bit difficult to comprehend. Can you please show me how its done using that package?

Comment: What is the difference between answer and solution? Can you edit your question to provide an example ?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda: Answer = final answer of the problem. Solution = the entire mathematical process involved in reaching the final answer.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda I have added a picture for clarificiation, I hope my intent is clear now.

Comment: Now I understand better your requirements but sorry I don't see how it can be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code to your preamble should do the trick

```
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\ifshortanswers%
\NewEnviron{shortanswer}{\ifshortanswers Ans. \BODY\fi}% Customize here
\def\printshortanswers{\shortanswerstrue}
```

Then you use

```
\begin{shortanswer}
42
\end{shortanswer}
```

to add answers and `\printshortanswers` to print the answers.

You can change how the answers are displayed by changing the line marked with `% Customize here`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it opened up a slew of possibilities.